# How to cycle a Pandas dataframe grouping by hierarchical multiindex from top to bottom and store results

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, pandas-groupby, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to create a forecasting process using hierarchical time series. My problem is that I can't find a way to create a for loop that hierarchically extracts daily time series from a pandas dataframe grouping the sum of quantities by date. The resulting daily time series should be passed to a function inside the loop, and the results stored in some other object.

## Dataset

The initial dataset is a table that represents the daily sales data of 3 hierarchical levels: city, shop, product. The initial table has this structure:

```
+============+============+============+============+==========+
| Id_Level_1 | Id_Level_2 | Id_Level_3 |    Date    | Quantity |
+============+============+============+============+==========+
| Rome       | Shop1      | Prod1      | 01/01/2015 |       50 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| Rome       | Shop1      | Prod1      | 02/01/2015 |       25 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| Rome       | Shop1      | Prod1      | 03/01/2015 |       73 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| Rome       | Shop1      | Prod1      | 04/01/2015 |       62 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| ...        | ...        | ...        | ...        |      ... |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| Milan      | Shop3      | Prod9      | 31/12/2018 |      185 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| Milan      | Shop3      | Prod9      | 31/12/2018 |      147 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| Milan      | Shop3      | Prod9      | 31/12/2018 |      206 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

Each City (Id_Level_1) has many Shops (Id_Level_2), and each one has some Products (Id_Level_3). Each shop has a different mix of products (maybe shop1 and shop3 have product7, which is not available in other shops). All data are daily and the measure of interest is the quantity.

## Hierarchical Index (MultiIndex)

I need to create a tree structure (hierarchical structure) to extract a time series for each "node" of the structure. I call a "node" a cobination of the hierarchical keys, i.e. "Rome" and "Milan" are nodes of Level 1, while "Rome|Shop1" and "Milan|Shop9" are nodes of level 2. In particulare, I need this on level 3, because each product (Id_Level_3) has different sales in each shop of each city. Here is the strict hierarchy. 
Nodes of level 3 are "Rome, Shop1, Prod1", "Rome, Shop1, Prod2", "Rome, Shop2, Prod1", and so on. The key of the nodes is logically the concatenation of the ids.

For each node, the time series is composed by two columns: Date and Quantity.

```py
# MultiIndex dataframe
Liv_Labels = ['Id_Level_1', 'Id_Level_2', 'Id_Level_3', 'Date']
df.set_index(Liv_Labels, drop=False, inplace=True)
```

The I need to extract the aggregated time series in order but keeping the hierarchical nodes.

**Level 0:**

```py
Level_0 = df.groupby(level=['Data'])['Qta'].sum()
```

**Level 1:**

```py
# Node Level 1 "Rome"
Level_1['Rome'] = df.loc[idx[['Rome'],:,:]].groupby(level=['Data']).sum()

# Node Level 1 "Milan"
Level_1['Milan'] = df.loc[idx[['Milan'],:,:]].groupby(level=['Data']).sum()
```

**Level 2:**

```py
# Node Level 2 "Rome, Shop1"
Level_2['Rome',] = df.loc[idx[['Rome'],['Shop1'],:]].groupby(level=['Data']).sum()

... repeat for each level 2 node ...

# Node Level 2 "Milan, Shop9"
Level_2['Milan'] = df.loc[idx[['Milan'],['Shop9'],:]].groupby(level=['Data']).sum()
```

## Attempts

I already tried creating dictionaries and multiindex, but my problem is that I can't get a proper "node" use inside the loop. I can't even extract the unique level nodes keys, so I can't collect a specific node time series.

```py
# Get level labels
Level_Labels = ['Id_Liv'+str(n) for n in range(1, Liv_Num+1)]+['Data']

# Initialize dictionary
TimeSeries = {} 

# Get Level 0 time series
TimeSeries["Level_0"] = df.groupby(level=['Data'])['Qta'].sum()

# Get othe levels time series from 1 to Level_Num
for i in range(1, Liv_Num+1):
    TimeSeries["Level_"+str(i)] = df.groupby(level=Level_Labels[0:i]+['Data'])['Qta'].sum()
```

## Desired result

I would like a loop the cycles my dataset with these actions:

1. Creates a structure of all the unique node keys
2. Extracts the node time series grouped by Date and Quantity
3. Store the time series in a structure for later use

Thanks in advance for any suggestion! Best regards.
FR

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a switch dataset that I polled from an sql database where each port on the respective switch has a data frame which has a time series. So to access this time series information for each specific port I represented the switches by their IP addresses and the various number of ports on the switch, and to make sure I don't re-query what I already queried before I used the .unique() method to get unique queries of each.

I set my index to be the IP and Port indices and accessed the port information like so:

```
def yield_df(df):
for ip in df.index.get_level_values('ip').unique():
    for port in df.loc[ip].index.get_level_values('port').unique():
        yield df.loc[ip].loc[port]
```

Then I cycled the port data frames with a for loop like so:

```
for port_df in yield_df(adb_df):
```

I'm sure there are faster ways to carry out these procedures in pandas but I hope this helps you start solving your problem